# Storing only the id of two related tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Like ownership.

Suppose I already have two models:

```
person name:string
dog name:string
```

Now I need to have the third table - ownership.

In a normal relational database, I only need to store the two ids from those tables, but rails automatically generates them. So how can I reference them?

```
rails generate model Ownership XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a relationship model, like this:

```
rails generate model ownerships person:references dog:references
rails db:migrate
```

app/models/ownership.rb:

```
class Ownership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :dog
end
```

app/models/person.rb:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :dogs, through: :ownerships
end
```

Now you can do:

```
john  = Person.create(name: 'John')
doggy = Dog.create(name: 'Doggy')

john.dogs << doggy
```

And you just added a dog to John's ownerships. You can find them like this:

```
puts john.dogs.first.name
# => "Doggy"
```

If you look at your generated schema.rb:

```
  create_table "ownerships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "person_id"  # Here are your two ids
    t.integer  "dog_id"     #
    # ...
```

---

I would recommend you going through [Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-the_relationship_model). In the last section he implements a relationship model with very thorough explanation.

Comment: thank you. i didn't know i can create a model with only references

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a has_ :through relationship or a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. Check the docs for more info (you can find detailed explanation on how to set up the DB and relationship.)It is a standard issue in rails: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html